# What is the name of this plant or shrub?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I just found a plant in India.

[image]

Here is its leaf.

[image]

I tried looking it up on flowers of India & wikipedia, but both databases are too 
much to read manually.

Physical description:

Each Stem has 6 leaves on it, **Leaves** are opposite & **Elliptic** shape, **Entire** margin & **Pinnate** veins on it.

I am thinking it is shrub, not a tree.

Comment: I replaced **night time** images with **day time**. Hope this will help to ID this species easy.